Even though there is a secondary data file, I get an error saying the primary data file is full
In SQL Server, my database was growing on disk A. Since disk A was full, I configured the database to grow on disk B. I made the necessary adjustments as a secondary data file in the Properties-Files section of the database. When I run the index maintenance job, I get the following error in the index reorganize step.
Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.XX' in database 'YY' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 1105). The step failed.

You probably rebuilding index and it temporarily requires double storage as the current size of index on the same file group the object resides. Try SORT_IN_TEMPDB option with your index rebuild to move the temp results to tempdb file group or better REORGANIZE only .If moving some tables to new file group is possible then rebuild clustered index on new file group
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ix_name
   ON dbo.table_name(fields,..)
   WITH DROP_EXISTING
   ON [filegroup_name]

